# Laravel + Inertia + Vue Flash Message on delete not working

Tags: laravel, vuejs3, inertiajs

I am making a simple CRUD with Laravel, Inertia and Vue...
All functionalities work fine but on delete the flash message dont work well.

I follow the documentation and all the others functionalities work perfectly but the delete dont show the flash message.

Please help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Laravel code
class HandleInertiaRequests extends Middleware
{
    public function share(Request $request)
    {
        return array_merge(parent::share($request), [
            'flash' => [
                'message' => fn () => $request->session()->get('message')
            ],
        ]);
    }
}

// vue3 code
<template>
  <main>
    <header></header>
    <content>
      <div v-if="$page.props.flash.message" class="alert">
        {{ $page.props.flash.message }}
      </div>
      <slot />
    </content>
    <footer></footer>
  </main>
</template>
```

> {{ $page.props.flash.message }} will work in template, If you want to
> get message in strip so you has to follow the below code.

```
import {usePage} from '@inertiajs/vue3'

const message = usePage().props.flash.message;
```

> You can get anything from usePage() or $page in template if you have
> shared it in middleware HandleInertiaRequests.
>
> Add dd() in HandleInertiaRequests and sure that message is available
> here or not.